# Jquerymobile - .xls file in mobile browser

Tags: jquery

How to view .xls , .doc, .odt, .pdf and .ppt in **mobile browser** using **jquerymobile** framework.

Any one help me.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this just by using jquerymobile framework.

So there are several ways:

- Let user download .xls or any other kind of file. -- Easiest way, but maybe not convenient for end-user;
- Transform each file format to html on the server side. But this very depends on a platform you use (php, django, asp.net, ...?). -- This is more hard to do, and cannot be fit into one subject in S.O. You need to open a file (xls, doc, .. whatever), render a simple html, and output to end-user.